# Interpret output for `iw list`

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wpa2

How should I interpret the output below? I want to use the device to simultaneously connect to a WiFi network (a wireless router) and to broadcast a separate local network from the device. Is this possible? Or will I need to add another wireless interface device (e.g. a wireless USB dongle)?

```
$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
    ...
    ...
    ...
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 1
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you asked, as long as you are okay with publishing your local network on the same channel as the existing AP (wireless router) that you are joining in managed client mode.

Here's the breakdown:

- "managed" is 802.11 jargon for a wireless client that is connected an AP.
- "AP" is 802.11 jargon for a device that publishes a normal Wi-Fi network for clients to join.

Of the two valid interface combinations listed in the `iw list` output, only the second one includes both "managed" and "AP" mode, and that one has a restriction that it can only use a single channel.

In general, a single Wi-Fi module can only be on one channel at a time, but managed mode and those P2P (peer-to-peer) modes have mechanisms to let devices switch between channels without missing packets. Unfortunately an AP must always be on the channel on which it is publishing its network or it could miss packets from its clients, so you must stay on the same channel all the time if you are using AP mode. That is why the valid combination that includes AP mode is restricted to a single channel.

So Yes, you can simultaneously connect to a Wi-Fi network and create a separate local network from that device, as long as both are on the same channel.